# Is it possible to use Bukkit for Minecraft to define a new kind of mob?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I'd like to write a Minecraft mod which adds a new type of mob.  Is that possible?  I see that, in Bukkit, [`EntityType` is a predefined enum](http://jd.bukkit.org/apidocs/org/bukkit/entity/EntityType.html), which leads me to believe there may not be a way to add a new type of entity.  I'm hoping that's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would only be possible with client-side mods as well, sadly. You could look into Spout, (http://www.spout.org/) which is a client mod which provides an API for server-side plugins to do more on the client, but without doing something client side, this is impossible.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can!

I'd direct you to some tutorials on the Bukkit forums. Specifically:

- [Creating a Meteor Entity](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-intermediate-custom-entities-meteor.93899/)
- [Modifying the Behavior of a Mob or Entity](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-how-to-customize-the-behaviour-of-a-mob-or-entity.54547/page-2#post-1281468)

Disclaimer: the first is written by me.

You cannot truly add an *entirely* new mob just via Bukkit. You'd have to use Spout to give it a different skin. However, in the case you simply want a mob, and are content with sharing a skin of another entity, then it can be done.

The idea is injecting the EntityType values via Java's [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html). It would look something like this:

```
public static void load() {
  try {

    Method a = EntityTypes.class.getDeclaredMethod("a", Class.class, String.class, int.class);
    a.setAccessible(true); 
    a.invoke(a, YourEntityClass.class, "Your identifier, can be anything", id_map);

} catch (Exception e) {
//Insert handling code here
}
}
```

I think the above is fairly straightforward. We get a handle to the private method, make it public, and invoke its registration method.`id_map` contains the entity id to map your entity to. 12 is that of a fireball. The mapping can be found in `EntityType.class`. Note that these ids should *not* be confused with their [packet designations](http://wiki.vg/Entities#Mobs). The two are completely different.

Lastly, you actually need to spawn your entity. MC will continue spawning the default entity, since we haven't removed it from the map. But its just a matter of calling the `net.minecraft.server.spawnEntity(your_entity, SpawnReason.CUSTOM)`.

If you need a skin, I suggest you look into [Spout](http://www.spout.org/)Plugin. It does require running the Spout client to join to such a server, but the possibilities at that point are literally infinite.

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying I can make a new entity with entirely custom behavior as long as it uses the skin of an existing entity?

Comment: +1 on the detailed explanation. This'll probably need an edit when MCAPI is released though :')

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to add new entities, but it is possible to edit entity behaviors for example one time, I made it so that you could tame iron golems and they followed you around.

Comment: Can you post a link to source code for that, if it's still available?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can sort of achieve custom looking human entities by accessing player entities and tweaking network packets

It's expensive as you need to create a player account to achieve this that then gets used to act as a mob. You then spawn a named entity and give it the same behaviour AI as you would with an existing mob. Keep in mind however you will need to write the AI yourself (you could borrow code straight from craftbukkit/bukkit) and you will need to push the movement and events of this mob to players within sight .. As technically speaking all your doing is pushing packets to the client from the serve on what's actually happening but if your outside that push list nothing will happen as other players will see you being knocked around by invisible something :) it's a bit of a mental leap :)

I'm using this concept to create Npc that act as friendly and factional armies. I've also used mobs themselves as friendly entities (if you belong to a dark faction)

I'd like to personally see future server API that can push model instructions to the client for server specific cache as well as the ability to tell a client where to download mob skins ..

It's doable today but I'd have to create a plugin for the client to achieve this which is then back to a game of annoyance especially when mojang push out a new release and all the plugins take forever to rise with its tide

In all honesty this entire ecosystem could be managed more strategically but right now I think it's just really ad hoc product management (speaking as a former product manager of .net I'd love to work on this strategy it would be such a fun gig)